# Can we use Flink REST API with Flink "Application" Deployment mode?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have first stated a job with Flink "Application" mode and then tried to use Flink REST API to upload a jar on that cluster. Upload jar API returns 404 Not Found error. is it true that Flink REST API only works with session mode and it is not supported with Application/Per Job modes

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Not found: /jars/upload"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flink command line  to submit job in application mode.

```bash
$ ./bin/flink run-application \
    --target kubernetes-application \
    -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=my-first-application-cluster \
    -Dkubernetes.container.image.ref=custom-image-name \
    local:///opt/flink/usrlib/my-flink-job.jar
```

You should specify the `kubernetes-application` target and the cluster id.

Also the session mode command is：

```
# (1) Start Kubernetes session
$ ./bin/kubernetes-session.sh -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=my-first-flink-cluster

# (2) Submit example job
$ ./bin/flink run \
    --target kubernetes-session \
    -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=my-first-flink-cluster \
    ./examples/streaming/TopSpeedWindowing.jar

# (3) Stop Kubernetes session by deleting cluster deployment
$ kubectl delete deployment/my-first-flink-cluster
```

Rest api is initially designed for monitor. The rest api It doesn't support submit flink job in application mode now.
The request url is like this:`{{cluster_address}}/jars/xxx.jar/run`.

when you submit a job via rest api, it assumes you have started Kubernetes session, and the cluster address is fixed in the url, it is samilar to sumibt a job in session mode.